# Is it possible to add something above the Facebook Wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm close to what I want at https://www.facebook.com/wheeleez?sk=app_107608005997641

I want to put these videos above my wall, but still retain all the functionality of the wall.  The Share / "Write Something..."

I'm using this Facebook app:  https:   //apps.facebook.com/wheeleez-videos/ for which the canvas is https:   //www.wheeleez.com/facebook/video-wall/

But I'm losing the "Write something..."

I'm using the plugin from http:   //www.neosmart.de/social-media/fb-wall to put my wall on https:   //www.wheeleez.com/facebook/video-wall/

Here's a jpg mockup of exactly what I'm trying to do http://wheeleez.com/images/FacebookAppScreenshot.jpg

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution to make it work, but in my opinion this seems like something that should be in a different tab. You can make a FBML tab that the user will see when they visit your page for the first time and put those videos there. You may be able to have that be the default tab all the time, not sure. I hope that helps. That solution works well for a lot of pages.